# VBNet DataGridView displaying SQL DB - Date / Time formating not working

Tags: datagridview

Dears 
I want you just to know that im absolutely not a developer and I dont have any knowledge regarding coding VB.

I am actually building a small tool to analyze data which gets writte to a DB.
I got 3 columns on the DB - The 3rd Column is a "DateTime" column in the sql DB.

If I display the column in DataGridView it gets displayed in the following format --> MM/dd/yyyy
I want to achieve that it gets displayed as dd/MM/yyyy - I barely tried everything I found while googling but nothing worked..

Can you please assist me in this inquiry?

Please see below code.

Note that I removed every code I tried to format the TimeData column below. For example --> datagridview1.columns("TimeData").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class VBNET_SQL_Datagridview_Search
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server= DBserver;Database=HiddenDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;")
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FilterData("")
End Sub


Public Sub FilterData(valueToSearch As String)
valueToSearch & "'%"
    Dim searchQuery As String = "SELECT * From database WHERE CONCAT(Sender, Recipient, TimeData) like '%" & valueToSearch & "%'"
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(searchQuery, connection)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    NewMethod()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table




End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone just runs into the same issue. 
I was able to fix this **by formating the DateTime field to sql standard yyyy-mm-dd.**
After that the vb sw displayed the date as I requested it.